# What does a Real Number Object look like as a sheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I understand that a Natural Number Object, when considered as an object in a sheaf topos, consists of a sheaf whose sections are locally constant functions. This makes me wonder what a Real Number Object looks like. I'm aware that there's a distinction to be made between Cauchy Real Numbers and Dedekind Real Numbers. However I'm not aware of what either type of sheaf has as its sections.

Comment: Cauchy real numbers form the sheaf of locally constant real-valued functions and Dedekind real numbers form the sheaf of continuous real-valued functions.  See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/real+numbers+object#in_sheaves_on_a_topological_space

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Ah, thanks!!